# 2010 Volkswagen EOS stuck in Park

Tags: vw, troubleshooting, automatic-transmission, parking, solenoid

I have a 2010 Volkswagen EOS only summer driven.  I parked it in November 2017 and went to use it last week after sitting for 6 months and the car will not shift out of park (automatic transmission).  Everything else seems to be working fine.
The dealer says I need to replace the entire Shifter Assembly - Volkswagen part #:(5K1-713-025-BK) because the shifter solenoid cannot be replaced by itself.  They say the solenoid is integrated into the shifter assembly and to replace the solenoid means replacing the entire assembly.  Its about $700-800 for the part and about 6 hours labor.
Does this sound right to you?  It seems to be a lot of money for a simple repair of a shifter solenoid.
Thanks Don

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! Is the solenoid the stealership is talking about the one which is activated when you press the brake pedal? If so, there should be a slot next to the shifter which allows you to shift it out of park (most cars have a small plug over it).

Comment: Yes.  That is the correct solenoid.  If I remove the shift lever cover, I can push down on a yellow lever that allows the car to shift into Drive.  It can be driven like that but I would like to fix it.

Comment: Oh, no doubt you want it fixed! I was just making sure what you were talking about. I've looked at several parts places online and I don't see where the solenoid is offered separately (doesn't even show up with the shifter assembly), so can not make a definitive call for you.